# Update ViewBag with jQuery and rendering results

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have an MVC3 application which uses ViewBag variables to dynamically fetch data from database and dynamically generate the interface.

I am using jQuery to call action method to insert some values to the database and update a ViewBag variable accordingly. I want to refresh the div with the new ViewBag values returned after the update from server...Cant really figure how to do that. Thanks

This is my View code:

```
    <div id="phys">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>IPSS</legend>


                @foreach (var parameter in ViewBag.four.Parameters)
                {

                    @MyHelpers.ParameterList(parameter, ViewBag.four.ParametersValues, "ParametersList")


                }
                <button type="button" onclick="print()" class="t-button">
        Add Physician</button>

        <table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            Physician
        </th>
        <th>
            Time
        </th>
        <th>
            Delete
        </th>


    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in ViewBag.physicians.ParametersValues)
        {
            <tr>
                @{var items = ((string)row.Value).Split('|');}

                <td>@items[0]
                </td>
                <td>@items[1]
                </td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteVisitParameter", new { vpid = @row.VisitParameterID })</td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>

        </fieldset>
        </div>
```

**This is my jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        print = function () {

            //$.post("/visit/physicians", { phy: $("#ParamList7 option:selected").text(), vID: '@ViewBag.VisitID' })

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Content("~/visit/physicians")',


                data: { phy: $("#ParamList7 option:selected").text(), vID: '@ViewBag.VisitID' },
                success: function (data) {

                    //What Shall I do here to update div #phys with new View Data??
                },
                fail: function (msg) {
                    alert("Fail"); ;
                }
            });



        };


    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

modified the AJAX method in javascript

```
$.ajax({
                        cache:false,
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "@(Url.Action("visit", "physicians"))",
                        data: { phy: $("#ParamList7 option:selected").text(), vID: '@ViewBag.VisitID'},
                        success: function (data) {

                           // perform operation after successful call 


                        },
                        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                            alert('fail');

                        }  
                    });
```

// In Controller

```
public ActionResult visit(string phy,string vID)
{

  //perform your operation here and return result in JSON 

   return Json(new {result =""},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

NOTE: make sure all parameter must have value calling action through java script.

this will call your Action, if want to update values after performing functionality then you must be pass result in JSON and perform the operation in **success function** of java script

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, I used your code and returned the new ViewBag value as follows

Comment: Ok. Thanks very much fro your response, I did use your code and returned the new updated ViewBag in the result as follows:

ViewBag.physicians = GetVisitSectionParamters(vID, 100).ParametersValues[0].Value;

        return Json(new { result = ViewBag.physicians }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet